# Pope effect on pizza - Regression with presence absence and similarity data as dependent variables

Tags: regression, bayesian, spatial

I'm trying to figure out the right way to set up a regression when the dependent variables are presence absence data (of pizzas), and the similarity between the *present* pizzas. Bear with the story:

## Figuring out the pope's effect on pizzeria menus

You are a pizza historian, and recently received  funding to study a phenomenon that has been haunting the field for decades - the pope effect.

It is well known that popes frequent mutually exclusive groups of pizzeria's during their tenure. An open question that remains is: **Does a pope's presence change any of the items on the menu of a pizzeria?**.  Specifically, in the following cartoon causal model, you want to know the strength of the arrows coming from the pope effect.

[image]

You collect data on 20 pizzerias, some of which were frequented by popes and other's not. Between them there are 10 possible menu items. Some menu items are at every pizza joint, some are rare.

[image]

[image]

When you examine the similarity data of the different pizzas, you get some tantalizing results:

[image]
It looks like, despite the high spatial correlation, JPII's pizza haunts have very similar mortadella pizza offerings, indicating those restaurants may have catered to his will. And Francis' favorite pizza places all have bistecca pizza on the menu, while none of the others do.

## What's the point?

1. Some types of pizza are just less diverse than others.

- you'd want to do a hierarchical model so each pizza can have it's own slope and intercept, but still share information to the other pizzas.

2. some pizzerias are so close together that you'd expect their menus and the pizzas on those menus to be really similar just based on geography.

- you'd want to model spatial autocorrelation somehow.

3. You want to estimate each pope's effect on the similarity of pizzas at the pizzerias they visit, as well as the presence/absence of pizza types.

- you have "missing" similarity data when pizzerias don't have a specific pizza

If it were just the presence absence data, I could imagine doing a model for each pizza $p$ and each menu $m$:

$\text{presence}_{pm} \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_{pm})$

$\text{logit}(p_{pm}) = \alpha_{pm} + \beta_{p\text{JPII}} + \beta_{p\text{BXVI}} + \beta_{p\text{F}}$

$\alpha_{p} \sim \text{MVNormal}(\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ \vdots \\0 \end{pmatrix},K)$

where $K$ reflects the spatial structure of the pizzerias, and the pope $\beta$'s are only affecting the pizzerias they go to.

I'm not sure how to amend this model to allow for a pope effect on similarities of the different menu items while also estimating the effect on presence absence. Any ideas?

The simulated pizza data are here if anyone wants to play with it: https://gist.github.com/elsherbini/f6bb6d57341ce898092f5cc548d5979b

Comment: This is a cool question! Sadly I don't have much time to think about it right now, but something seems off in the datafiles. The pairwise similarities are not symmetric - that is P01_P02_marinara is not the same as P02_P01_marinara. Is that correct? If so, what does that mean?

Comment: Good catch, that was a mistake in my janky simulation. The gist is updated now with only the upper triangle pairs in the data.

Comment: What is the source of this question? Did you come up with it by yourself or is it part of a book or class? In any case, I think the model you describe could be used as a baseline, and you could incorporate the spatial correlation via a Gaussian Process. Then compare the two models to see if the GP adds anything useful.

Comment: Really interesting! There's effectively actually another 'confounder': presence->similarity. I think the effect is theoretically identifiable, but there's going to be a *lot* of hierarchical adjustments.